# Does deleting my backup on my iPhone give me more space?

Tags: iphone

I'm running out of space on my iCloud and my storage in general. If I delete my backup, will I gain more space for pictures?

Answer (score 1):

If you disable/delete iCloud backups of your iOS device, it will indeed free up space in your iCloud account. This only means you will have more space available *in the cloud, not on the actual device.*

If you have [iCloud Photo Library](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264) enabled, note that your iCloud backups *will not* include that media since it’s already being uploaded to the cloud.

To free up space on your actual iOS *device* (again, assuming iCloud Photo Library is enabled), make sure that `Settings > iCloud > Photos > Optimize Storage` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Definitely it will. An easy way to free up a lot of space in iCloud for your pictures is to delete backups. If your iCloud storage is still almost full, maybe other cloud services are good for you. However, you should know that this is only for you to have more space on iCloud not your own devices.